# Cleaning a xml file from misplaced characters

Tags: xml

I have an XML file that is accessible by many people.
Sometimes people mistakenly leave characters which are not valid. (accidentally leaving some char, or after removing a begin-comment character, forget to remove the end-comment character).
For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<element>
    <cluster directory="Install">//
        <in_element execute="true"/>-->
    </cluster>
</element>
```

Somebody accidentally left the --> which closed a comment that was deleted, and accidentally pressed //.

What is the best way to deal with this? Is there a XML editor that can simply by parsing and writing it turn it into:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<element>
    <cluster directory="Install">
        <in_element execute="true"/>
    </cluster>
</element>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot imagine an automatic repair of XML files broken in the way you describe. You can do something to prevent broken XML in the first place:

1. Ask the people who can edit the XML file to validate it before saving.
2. Prescribe an XML editor that prevents the users editing the file from saving invalid XML.
3. Validate the XML file before storing it back to further use and reject it when invalid (and inform the last editing user of this).